# Comparing trends across multiple series

Tags: regression, linear-model, regression-coefficients

I have multiple series of data; each series is only made of 3 to 5 data points, so drawing any sort of statistical inference from any one series is tenuous. That being said, if you look at all the series together, it's apparent that there is a general increasing trend (i.e. all of the individual series have a positive gradient), with one outlying group (A2 in the image below).

For context; this data is from a manufacturing process. Each series is for a specific material, with a specific set of manufacturing parameters. I'm trying to demonstrate that the response is dependent on position.

[image: Response versus position, and standardised response based on subtraction of the mean of each series.]

Is there any reasonable statistical test or framework I could apply to say, with some level of confidence, that there is a trend in response? Is there any justifiable approach to e.g. comparing gradients and regression coefficients?

I appreciate I could apply some form of standardisation of each series (e.g. feature scaling, norm referencing etc - the above righthand plot just has mean of each series subtracted to bring them into similar ranges) and then just run regression on the whole dataset, but it feels like this masks the nuance of the data, and given the limited number of points in each series may be very sensitive to outliers.

Answer (score 0):

Five data points is simply not enough data. If there was seasonality how would you ever capture it? 50 data points is generally the minimum seen as required (and that is the low end and for monthly data I think). There are formal tests for trend, but they are not going to work I am sure with five data points.

Ignoring that it will likely not work in this case you may want to look up tests for stationarity. There are a number of these. Some have a null of stationarity and some non-stationarity (aka a trend).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_root_test

Be warned. This is not simple in practice. There are many issues such as the number of lags to use, power and the like that make this complex. Just plotting the data as you did is a good start. Because of issues of statistical power some recommend using a test with a null of stationarity and a test with a null of non-stationarity and see if they generate the same results.